Issues with Video Recording Duration and Smooth Playback when Using v4l2 framework to MP4 (FFmpeg)
I'm trying to record a video from a USB device with v4l2 framework and save it in MP4 format using FFmpeg. My sample code successfully captures and saves the video, but I'm running into some issues:
The recorded video duration is shorter than expected. For instance:
When recording a 1-minute video at 1280x720, the output file only has 58 or 59 seconds. For 1920x1080, the duration is even more off — only about 28 or 30 seconds, instead of the expected 1 minute. Additionally, the video is not smooth. There are noticeable drops in frames and playback inconsistencies.
My setup:
Using a USB device with v4l2 framework Saving the video in MP4 format Tested with different resolutions (1280x720, 1920x1080) I've attached my sample code below. Could someone help me figure out why I'm experiencing these issues with video duration and smooth playback?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define WIDTH 1280
#define HEIGHT 720
#define FPS 30
#define DURATION 10 // Recording duration in seconds
#define BUFFER_COUNT 4 // Number of buffers

struct buffer {
    void *start;
    size_t length;
};

struct buffer *buffers;

void open_device(int *fd, const char *device) {
    *fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (*fd < 0) {
        perror("Cannot open video device");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void init_mmap(int fd) {
    struct v4l2_requestbuffers req;
    memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));
    req.count = BUFFER_COUNT;
    req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;

    if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req) < 0) {
        perror("Requesting buffer");
        exit(1);
    }

    buffers = calloc(req.count, sizeof(*buffers));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < req.count; ++i) {
        struct v4l2_buffer buf;
        memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        buf.index = i;

        if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &buf) < 0) {
            perror("Querying buffer");
            exit(1);
        }

        buffers[i].length = buf.length;
        buffers[i].start = mmap(NULL, buf.length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, buf.m.offset);

        if (MAP_FAILED == buffers[i].start) {
            perror("mmap");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

void start_capturing(int fd) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_COUNT; ++i) {
        struct v4l2_buffer buf;
        memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        buf.index = i;

        if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf) < 0) {
            perror("Queue buffer");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    enum v4l2_buf_type type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type) < 0) {
        perror("Start capture");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void stop_capturing(int fd) {
    enum v4l2_buf_type type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;

    if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMOFF, &type) < 0) {
        perror("Stop capture");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Video capture stopped.\n");
}

void unmap_buffers() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_COUNT; ++i) {
        if (munmap(buffers[i].start, buffers[i].length) < 0) {
            perror("munmap");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    free(buffers);
}

void initialize_ffmpeg(AVFormatContext **fmt_ctx, AVCodecContext **codec_ctx, AVStream **video_stream, const char *filename) {
    av_register_all();

    AVOutputFormat *fmt = av_guess_format(NULL, filename, NULL);
    if (!fmt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not determine output format\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(fmt_ctx, fmt, NULL, filename) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate format context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    *video_stream = avformat_new_stream(*fmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (!*video_stream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    *codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!*codec_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    (*codec_ctx)->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    (*codec_ctx)->width = WIDTH;
    (*codec_ctx)->height = HEIGHT;
    (*codec_ctx)->time_base = (AVRational){1, FPS};
    (*codec_ctx)->framerate = (AVRational){FPS, 1};
    (*codec_ctx)->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    (*codec_ctx)->gop_size = 10;
    (*codec_ctx)->max_b_frames = 1;

    av_opt_set(*codec_ctx, "preset", "fast", 0);
    av_opt_set_int(*codec_ctx, "crf", 23, 0);

    (*video_stream)->time_base = (*codec_ctx)->time_base;
    (*video_stream)->codecpar->codec_id = fmt->video_codec;
    (*video_stream)->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    (*video_stream)->codecpar->width = (*codec_ctx)->width;
    (*video_stream)->codecpar->height = (*codec_ctx)->height;
    (*video_stream)->codecpar->format = (*codec_ctx)->pix_fmt;

    if ((*fmt_ctx)->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
        (*codec_ctx)->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }

    if (avcodec_open2(*codec_ctx, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_from_context((*video_stream)->codecpar, *codec_ctx) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not copy codec parameters\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_open(&(*fmt_ctx)->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if (avformat_write_header(*fmt_ctx, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not write header\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void capture_and_encode(int fd, AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, AVCodecContext *codec_ctx, struct SwsContext *sws_ctx, AVStream *video_stream, int duration) {
    struct v4l2_buffer buffer;
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);

    frame->format = codec_ctx->pix_fmt;
    frame->width = codec_ctx->width;
    frame->height = codec_ctx->height;
    av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, codec_ctx->pix_fmt, 32);

    struct timespec start_time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start_time);
    double elapsed_time = 0;
    int64_t pts_counter = 0;
    int frame_count = 0;

    while (elapsed_time < duration) {
        fd_set fds;
        struct timeval tv;
        int r;

        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(fd, &fds);

        tv.tv_sec = 2;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        r = select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if (r == -1) {
            perror("select");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (r == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "select timeout\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        buffer.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        buffer.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;

        if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buffer) < 0) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN) continue;
            perror("Could not dequeue buffer");
            exit(1);
        }

        uint8_t *src_slices[1] = {buffers[buffer.index].start};
        int src_stride[1] = {WIDTH * 2}; // UYVY is 2 bytes per pixel

        sws_scale(sws_ctx, src_slices, src_stride, 0, HEIGHT, frame->data, frame->linesize);

        frame->pts = pts_counter;
        pts_counter += av_rescale_q(1, (AVRational){1, FPS}, codec_ctx->time_base);

        if (avcodec_send_frame(codec_ctx, frame) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        while (avcodec_receive_packet(codec_ctx, &packet) == 0) {
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet, codec_ctx->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
            packet.stream_index = video_stream->index;

            if (av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, &packet) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error writing frame\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            av_packet_unref(&packet);
        }
        printf("Processed frame %d\n", frame_count);

        if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buffer) < 0) {
            perror("Could not requeue buffer");
            exit(1);
        }
        frame_count++;
        struct timespec current_time;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &current_time);
        elapsed_time = (current_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec) + (current_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec) / 1e9;
        printf("Elapsed time: %f seconds\n", elapsed_time);
    }

    av_freep(&frame->data[0]);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    printf("Total frames processed: %d\n", frame_count);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <output file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    const char *output_file = argv[1];
    int fd;
    open_device(&fd, "/dev/video2");

    struct v4l2_format fmt;
    memset(&fmt, 0, sizeof(fmt));
    fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    fmt.fmt.pix.width = WIDTH;
    fmt.fmt.pix.height = HEIGHT;
    fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_UYVY;
    fmt.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE;

    if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt) < 0) {
        perror("Setting pixel format");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat != V4L2_PIX_FMT_UYVY) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Device does not support UYVY format\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    init_mmap(fd);
    start_capturing(fd);

    AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx = NULL;
    AVCodecContext *codec_ctx = NULL;
    AVStream *video_stream = NULL;

    initialize_ffmpeg(&fmt_ctx, &codec_ctx, &video_stream, output_file);

    struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = sws_getContext(WIDTH, HEIGHT, AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422,
                                                WIDTH, HEIGHT, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                                SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (!sws_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize SwsContext\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    capture_and_encode(fd, fmt_ctx, codec_ctx, sws_ctx, video_stream, DURATION);

    sws_freeContext(sws_ctx);
    av_write_trailer(fmt_ctx);
    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
    avformat_free_context(fmt_ctx);
    stop_capturing(fd);
    unmap_buffers();
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}


you are processing video capture, rescaling and encoding in the same thread. H264 software encoding is time-consuming activity, and when you are encoding the frame to H.264, some frames lost. For huge resolution encoding process takes more time, so you loss more. Try to separate camera capturing and other activities to different threads: first thread captures frames and put them to list. Second thread should process rescaling and encoding
